# Label font size in PredictorEffects plot in R

Tags: r, label, font-size

I am plotting an ordinal regression plot with the PredictorEffects function, where I need to increase the font size of my labels. I was using `cex` function to do the same, but I cannot change the font size of x-axis.

Here are the codes:

```
m1 = polr(as.factor(views)~ caste, data = data, Hess=TRUE)

plot(predictorEffects(m1), lines=list(multiline=TRUE), xlab = list("Caste", cex = 2), 
     ylab= list("attitude probability", cex = 2),  main=FALSE)
```

The `cex` function is working for y-axis but not for x-axis

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `cex.lab` function:

> The magnification to be used for x and y labels relative to the
> current setting of cex.

Here an example no `cex.lab`:

```
x <- rnorm(100)

plot(x, main = "plot")
```

Output:

[image]

Here `cex.lab=2`:

```
plot(x, main = "plot", cex.lab = 2)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It  seems to work with a normal plot but not work while plotting with Pedictoreffects